# 'Go Back' in Browser with auto fire a fuction

Tags: javascript

I have two divs, the 'red' div is displayed while the 'blue' div is hide.

When I go back in browser from the hyperlink in the hidden 'blue' div, the page will automatically go back to the 'red' div.

However, I would need it to go back to the 'blue' div.

How can I make this work? Thanks very much for all the help.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
#red{
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
color: Red;
border: solid;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#blue{
display: none;
height: 300px;
width: 600px;
color: Blue;
border: solid;
margin-bottom: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="red">11</div>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
<div id="blue">22</div>
</a>
<input type="button" value="Show Red" onclick="document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('blue').style.display='none';"></input>
<input type="button" value="Show Blue" onclick="document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('blue').style.display='block';"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you should use localstorage..

Comment: You should learn about local storage using javaScript

Comment: @ShadowFiend Thank you very much for the info. Now I know where I should start.

Comment: @Roysh, Thank you very much for the info as well. I will learn them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localStorage to store values in browser.
Try this

```
<div id="red">11</div>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
<div id="blue">22</div>
</a>

<input type="button" value="Show Red" onclick="
document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('blue').style.display='none';
localStorage.setItem('currentRed', 'block');
localStorage.setItem('currentBlue', 'none');" />

<input type="button" value="Show Blue" onclick="
document.getElementById('red').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('blue').style.display='block';
localStorage.setItem('currentRed', 'none');
localStorage.setItem('currentBlue', 'block');" />

<script>
    if(localStorage.getItem('currentBlue')){
          document.getElementById('blue').style.display = localStorage.getItem('currentBlue');
          document.getElementById('red').style.display = localStorage.getItem('currentRed');
    }
</script>
```